# Flex, marking column <s:datagrid ...>

Tags: apache-flex

I need to mark one column in spark datagrid. In

```
public function MyStyleFunc(data:Object):Object
        {
            return {fontWeight:"bold"};

            return null;
        }
```

Comment: you should create custom itemrenderer for that.

Comment: Thanks, can you help me in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37153929/flex-as3-how-to-open-docx-odt-file ?